# MySQL IF then with math

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

Is it possible to do an mysql if/then statement with math?

Say...

```
    if product_name = "apple"
    then divide product_price by 4
    else do no math on product_price
```

Link to a tutorial on something like this or any help/direction would be appreciated.

I ended using bluefeet's method and up with this. Sample for anyone else that may need in the future,

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    12345_parts.*,
    12345_parts.install_meter +
    12345_parts.meter_life -
    12345_parts.prior_meter
    AS nextdue,
       CASE 
          WHEN 12345_parts.part_name = "JET ENGINE"
          THEN 12345_parts.meter_life + 12345_parts.install_meter - 12345_parts.prior_meter - status_12345.meter / 4
          ELSE 12345_parts.meter_life + 12345_parts.install_meter - 12345_parts.prior_meter - status_12345.meter
       END AS remainder
    FROM 12345_parts, status_12345
    WHERE 12345_parts.overhaul LIKE '%HLY%'
    AND 12345_parts.active='ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
   case 
      when product_name = 'apple' 
      then product_price/4
      else product_price
   end as price
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(product_name = "apple", product_price / 4, product_price) price 
FROM products;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, you can just do:

```
IF (product_name = "apple")
BEGIN 
  SELECT product_name, (product_price/4)
  FROM table
END
```

Answer (score 0):

[IF Then Instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)

Straight from the MySQL site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
select If(product_name = "apple",product_price/4,product_price) as cal from tableName
```